# OpenCV Android - How to draw a circle/rectangle around contours?

Tags: java, android, opencv, draw, contour

I am new to openCV and therefor I have a few problems.

One question is how I can get the coordinates of contours to draw for example a circle around it.

My code so far looks like this:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR, -1);
<<code that I need>>
Core.circle(mRgba, new Point(150.0,150.0), 100, CONTOUR_COLOR, 5);
```

the contours are "extracted" and drawn on the surface the testcircle also, but how can I get the coordinates(bounds) from the contours to draw a circle around each of the contours.

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that [boundingRect](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) and [minEnclosingCircle](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle) are available for android too. These functions do directly what you want to do. You can find a very nice tutorial that does exactly this, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html).